# Llevar recuento de dias para rentar un carro, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciento una aplicacion en python, un simulador para rentar un auto, por ahora lo estoy haciendo con 1 carro en mi Stock.
el numero de autos y de dias se da  por un ramdom y segun el rango en el que caiga, se asigna la cantidad.

el flujo normal del programa seria:

al primer dia un cliente ordena n autos, por n dias. si por ejemplo ordena 2 autos por 3 dias, el unico auto que tiene no lo va a poder separar otro cliente al siguiente dia. hasta el 4° dia.

No se como llevar la cuenta de un carro que se reservo por 3 dias y que al siguiente no se pueda separar si no hasta el 4° dia.

pongo el siguiente modelo que plantie.

```
       Stock    1               
DIA Aleatorio   Autos   A. Disponibles  Aleatorio   DIAS
1   0,267         1              1          0,561   2
2   0,232         1              0            -     0
3   0,670         1              1          0,899   3
4   0,438         2              0            -     0
5   0,159         1              0            -     0
6   0,295         3              1          0,820   4
7   0,784         2              0            -     0
8   0,862         2              0            -     0
9   0,262         2              0            -     0
10  0,718         1              1          0,557   4
```

Inicalimente cree la variable A.Disponibles  para que mirara si tengo o no el auto disponible para reservar.
la idea es que si en la iteracion anterior se separo un vehiculo por 3 dias, cuente 2 interaciones mas para que al cuarto dia pueda volver a ser reservado.

pongo un pedazo de codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar.

```
    from random import random

# --------------------------------------------------for AUTOS-------------------------------------
for i in range (5):
    stock=1             #carros en bodega
    nAutos = 0
    ADisp = 1
    AOcioso = 0
    nDias = 0 
    GananciaTotal=0

    aleatorioAuto = random()


    # --------------------------------------------------Si el aleatorio entra en el rango de probabilidades, aignele un numero----------
    if aleatorioAuto > 0 and aleatorioAuto < 0.10:          
        nAutos = 0
        print("La cantidad de autos es cero, no iteranciones\n ")

    elif aleatorioAuto >0.10 and aleatorioAuto < 0.20:      # Si el cliente ordena 1 Auto, solo se hace una iteracion de los dias que va a tomar    
        nAutos = 1

        aleatorioDia=random()

        if aleatorioDia > 0 and aleatorioDia < 0.40 and ADisp != 0:
            nDias = 1
            ganancia = 350 * nDias
            GananciaTotal += ganancia

        elif aleatorioDia > 0.35 and aleatorioDia < 0.75:
            nDias = 2
            ganancia = 350 * nDias
            GananciaTotal += ganancia

        elif aleatorioDia > 0.15 and aleatorioDia < 0.90:
            nDias = 3
            ganancia = 350 * nDias
            GananciaTotal += ganancia

        elif aleatorioDia > 0.10 and aleatorioDia < 1:
            nDias = 4
            ganancia = 350 * nDias
            GananciaTotal += ganancia

        perdidaO = 0
        perdidaS = 200*0
        print("dia",[i],"Autos \t ADisponibles\t dias \t ganancia \t perdida O \tperdida S")
        print("\t",str(nAutos),"\t\t",str(ADisp),"\t",str(nDias),"\t", str(ganancia),"\t\t", str(perdidaO),"\t\t", str(perdidaS))

        perdidatotal = perdidaO + perdidaS
        print("Ganancia Total: ", str(GananciaTotal), "Perdida: ", str(perdidatotal))



print("--------------------------Fin del programa---------------------------")
```

Aca la salida de mi programa hasta donde boy.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy buscando una forma de llevar la cuenta de los dias para que un cliente pueda volver a alquilar un auto.

Comment: Falta código después de `aleatorioAuto = random()`. La siguiente línea no puede empezar con `elif` sin un `if` previo.

Comment: 0k, Pongo el codigo completo

Comment: No entiendo bien qué significa la tabla. La columna `ADisponibles` entiendo que son los autos disponibles para rentar (es decir, los que se tienen menos los ya rentados). Pero ¿qué es la columna `Autos`? Si es el número de autos que se tienen ¿por qué aparecen y desaparecen? ¿Qué son las columnas `Aleatorio`? Por otro lado, la tabla que aparece al ejecutar el programa no tiene las mismas columnas que la que planteaste en un modelo. ¿Qué es lo de `ganancia` y `perdida`?

Comment: Por otro lado tampoco veo clara la columna `dias`. ¿Es el número de días que se renta un auto en cada fila? ¿Cada fila representa el paso de un día? ¿Será `autos` los que se rentan en un día? En ese caso ¿cómo pueden rentarse más de los que hay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas que no se entienden muy bien en la descripción del problema, como para qué sirve la primera columna Aleatorios y la columna Auto.

No se si aún no has visto la **programación orientada a objetos**, pero en el caso de que haya múltiples autos (como mencionas en el enunciado) la complejidad del problema aumentaría considerablemente. Al trabajar con objetos, la complejidad permanecería casi igual, como si fuera con un solo elemento.

En mi propuesta, que a lo mejor no es exactamente lo que estás buscando, pero te puede servir como guía, trabajo con una cantidad de vehículos que están en la lista `vehículos`. Cada elemento es convertido a objeto donde se le pasa a la **clase** el identificador (en este caso el nombre) y el precio de renta de ese vehículo.

Luego por cada iteración del `while` (los días que transcurren) se evalúa en la `clase` si el objeto está disponible para alquilar. Si es así se genera un numero al azar, de lo contrario se cobra el día y se resta un día a la cantidad de días que se alquiló.

```
from random import random

class Auto:
    def __init__(self, nombre_auto, renta_por_dia):
        self.nombre_auto = nombre_auto
        self.renta_por_dia = renta_por_dia
        self.dias_por_devolucion = 0
        self.ganancia = 0

    def sumar_ganancia(self):
        self.ganancia += self.renta_por_dia

    def restar_dia_por_devolver(self):
        self.dias_por_devolucion -= 1

    def verificar_disponibilidad(self):
        disponibilidad = 0 if self.dias_por_devolucion > 0 else 1
        return disponibilidad

# ######## INICIO DE EJECUCION ################
vehiculos = {'autoA':350, 'autoB':230, 'autoC':480}
dias_de_simulacion = 10
i = 1
objetos = []
for nombre_auto, precio_de_renta in vehiculos.items():
    # Convertir cada elemento en objeto
    objetos.append(Auto(nombre_auto, precio_de_renta))

print('DIA\tNOMBRE\tDISP\tALEAT\tDIAS\tCOBRO')
while i <= dias_de_simulacion:
    for autoObj in objetos:
        if autoObj.verificar_disponibilidad() > 0:
            # Si el vehiculo esta disponible se genera un numero al azar para ese objeto
            aleatorioAuto = random()
            if aleatorioAuto > 0.61:
                dias_de_renta = 4
            elif aleatorioAuto > 0.31:
                dias_de_renta = 3
            elif aleatorioAuto > 0.21:
                dias_de_renta = 2
            elif aleatorioAuto > 0.10:
                dias_de_renta = 1
            else:
                dias_de_renta = 0 # No se rento el auto
            autoObj.dias_por_devolucion = dias_de_renta
            print('{}\t{}\t1\t{}\t{}\t-'.format(i, autoObj.nombre_auto, str(aleatorioAuto)[0:5], dias_de_renta))
        else:
            # Si el vehiculo no esta disponible, es porque esta siendo usado, por lo que se cobra el dia
            autoObj.sumar_ganancia()
            autoObj.restar_dia_por_devolver()
            print('{}\t{}\t0\t-\t-\t+${}'.format(i, autoObj.nombre_auto, autoObj.renta_por_dia))
    i += 1

# Total de ganancia
print()
for autoObj in objetos:
    print("El {} ganó ${} ".format(autoObj.nombre_auto, autoObj.ganancia))

print("--------------------------Fin del programa---------------------------")
```

Un ejemplo de la salida para 10 días de simulación

```
DIA     NOMBRE  DISP    ALEAT   DIAS    COBRO
1       autoA   1       0.452   3       -
1       autoB   1       0.844   4       -
1       autoC   1       0.128   1       -
2       autoA   0       -       -       +$350
2       autoB   0       -       -       +$230
2       autoC   0       -       -       +$480
3       autoA   0       -       -       +$350
3       autoB   0       -       -       +$230
3       autoC   1       0.684   4       -
4       autoA   0       -       -       +$350
4       autoB   0       -       -       +$230
4       autoC   0       -       -       +$480
5       autoA   1       0.544   3       -
5       autoB   0       -       -       +$230
5       autoC   0       -       -       +$480
6       autoA   0       -       -       +$350
6       autoB   1       0.444   3       -
6       autoC   0       -       -       +$480
7       autoA   0       -       -       +$350
7       autoB   0       -       -       +$230
7       autoC   0       -       -       +$480
8       autoA   0       -       -       +$350
8       autoB   0       -       -       +$230
8       autoC   1       0.085   0       -
9       autoA   1       0.493   3       -
9       autoB   0       -       -       +$230
9       autoC   1       0.371   3       -
10      autoA   0       -       -       +$350
10      autoB   1       0.618   4       -
10      autoC   0       -       -       +$480

El autoA ganó $2450
El autoB ganó $1610
El autoC ganó $2880
--------------------------Fin del programa---------------------------
```

Comment: Me sirvio tu respuesta, en mi caso nombreAuto es la cantidad de autos que el cliente reserva, al no haber autos en el stock, se cobra una multa por no tenelo disponible.